# Print your username by ONLY using the characters in your username

Tags: string, kolmogorov-complexity, popularity-contest, restricted-source

You have to print out your username, by only using the characters in your username.

Standard loopholes are forbidden

This is not [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest does not win

Don't modify your username please

And each language be used one time

Comment: This isn't very interesting, and it's not fair to limit answerers by their username. It's like many [tag:kolgomorov-complexity] problems, but without the possibility to do anything creative.

Comment: @Wezi understood this is no longer [code-golf]

Comment: But a question [must also have an objective winning criterion.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8130/why-do-we-have-objective-winning-criteria/8135#8135)

Comment: Well now it has no winning criterion... maybe popularity-contest?

Comment: 1) Modifying your username to change your score’s a standard loophole, don’t worry about that. 2) this is now missing a scoring criteria, and is therefore off-topic

Comment: Yeah made it a popularity contest

Comment: I don't think this should be closed. It's not particularly interesting, but it has a (somewhat) objective winning criterion and it's perfectly clear what the task is.

Comment: [Keg, 80 bytes](https://tio.run/##y05N///fqKLCSJda0FDX8P9/AA "Keg – Try It Online") - I realized that don't have to change my username to solve this challenge!

Comment: @2x-1 a nice one indeed

Answer (score 7):

## [Swap](https://github.com/splcurran/Swap), 39 bytes

```
'n'e'i'r'B'''O' 'r'o'n'o'Cooooooooooooo
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky5PLPj/Xz1PPVU9U71I3UldXd1fXQHIygeK5as75yOD//8B)

I thought it would make sense for me to participate in this challenge, considering I have both spaces and the `'` character at my disposal. Terminates, I think, by crashing. Doesn't use the Swapping nature of the language.

Comment: FYI, any username with a single quote is very easy in APL: [`'Conor O''Brien'`,16 bytes](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=U3fOz8svUvBXV3cqykzNUwcA&f=AwA&i=AwA&r=tryAPL&l=apl-dyalog&m=tradfn&n=f).

Comment: @Bubbler that would also work in Python REPL

Comment: @Wasif No, it doesn't print the single quote in the middle in Python REPL.

Answer (score 5):

## [V (vim)](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 7 bytes

```
iDingus
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/P9MlMy@9tPj/fwA)

Yep, I sure am.

Comment: This must be where Apple got the inspiration for all its iThings.

Comment: @Bubbler I hear Steve Jobs was really keen on the iDingus until the marketing department got involved.

Answer (score 1):

## Charcoal, 4 bytes

```
Wezl
```

I hope I remembered how Charcoal works?

Answer (score 0):

## Text, 6 bytes

```
hakr14
```

---

Yucky bad trivial solution. Basically, every program in Text is a quine.

Comment: so ‘Text’ is a cat implementation?

Comment: No, it doesn't take input. Any .txt file is a Text program, producing its contents exactly.

Comment: Wow, Also [works as PHP](https://tio.run/##K8go@P8/IzG7yNDk/38A).

Comment: cat doesn't take any input either; when run on a file, it reproduces the contents of that file exactly

Comment: Ah, sorry, you meant the cat command. Typically `cat` refers to a program which outputs its input.

Answer (score 0):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 22 bytes

```
caird coinheringaahing
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K85JLM5ILf7/PzkxsyhFITk/My8jtSgzLz0xMQNI/v8PAA)

I may have chosen the wrong username to win this :/

Comment: Don't worry this is no longer [code-golf], a [popularity-contest[